# UICollectionView inside StackView - Interface Builder warning size will be (8,0) at runtime

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView inside a StackView. IB is giving a warning:

```
size will be (8,0) at runtime but (150,150) on the canvas.
```

No error at runtime - it all displays correctly.

This ONLY happens when the CollectionView is inside a StackView. As soon as I drag it outside StackView into UIView, error disappears.

I tried setting up layout in viewDidLayoutSubviews() as suggested by other posts on similar subjects but it doesn't remove the warning in IB.

Appreciate if someone could help me understand where this (8,0) size comes from! I have set Cell's size to custom 150,150 and also layout cell size in CollectionView to 150,150.

Thanks 
Bandu

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found a solution while trying everything that I could think of. Earlier, I had a structure like this:

```
UIView
    UIStackView
        UICollectionView
```

Now, I have embedded CollectionView inside another UIView, like this:

```
UIView
    UIStackView
        UIView
            UICollectionView
```

And the warning disappears!

It seems that UICollectionView (and same is true with UITableView - just found out) expects 'superview' to be a derivative of UIView.

I am sure there should be a way to add the missing function as an 'extension' to UIStackView to be able to hold UICollectionView (or TableView).

If someone know how to fix it, please let me know. Meanwhile, I will keep using the solution that I discovered.

Thanks
Bandu